# The holomorphic version of Galois theory

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, galois-theory, covering-spaces

We identify the space of polynomials of degree n with $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\mathbb{C}^{n}$, that is an $n+1$ tuple $(a_{n},a_{n-1},\ldots,a_{0})$  with $a_{n} \neq 0$ is identified with $p(z)=a_{n}z^{n} +\ldots a_{1}z+a_{0}$. In this question we search for a holomorphic representation for the roots of P. That is, we search for holomorphic maps which send each polynomial $P$ to one of its roots. Motivating by the special case $n=2$ and the "Radical formula" for the roots,  it is natural to search for  an appropriate version of "Riemann surface of radical-type functions". So here is our question, precisely:

**Question:**

> Does there exist an $n+1$ dimensional  complex manifold M  with  a covering space structure $\pi \colon M \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and  a holomorphic  function $f \colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$, such that for every $\tilde{P} \in M$ with $\pi(\tilde{P})=P$, all $n$ roots of $P$ are arranged in the $n$-tuple $f(\tilde{P})$?

**Remark**:
Since "Galois Theory " is  an obstruction for existence  of a radical (algebraic) formulation for the roots, it was natural that we search for  a holomorphic analogy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing you are asking was much studied in connection with Hilbert Problem 13.
The roots of a polynomial of degree exactly $d$ form an unordered $d$-tuple. The set of
unordered $d$-tuples is called the configuration space. It is the factor of $C^d$
 over
the action of permutation group. It is equivalent to the space of
polynomials of degree exactly $d$ modulo multiplication by a non-zero constant.
One recent reference is http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403120v3, and it contains many other references. The version of Hilbert problem 13 asks whether this function, mapping a polynomial to its roots, can be represented as a composition of functions of fewer variables.

Answer (score 11):

Say $a_n=1$. You can obtain this map as a section of the map $\sigma$ sending the $n$-tuple of the roots $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ to the coefficients of the polynomial using the symmetric polynomials, corresponding to the equality $$\prod _{j=1}^n (z-r_j) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$$

This map is holomorphic, locally biholomorphic outside the union $\Delta$ of the diagonals ${r_j=r_i}$, $i\neq j$ (corresponding to multiple roots). $\sigma$ is a holomorphic covering of degree $n!$ outside $\Delta$, and the Riemann manifold of its "inverse" exists and provides a manifold $\hat M$ which can be compactified as a Riemann manifold $M$ for "$\sigma^{-1}$" (since $\sigma$ is polynomial).

The topological structure of the covering space $\hat M$ is that of the complement of the hyperplanes arrangement given by $\Delta$, so its fundamental group will be a braid group.

As you mentioned what you can write down is limited by Galois theory, so you're not going to have anything "explicit" starting from degree 5, so I'm afraid you'll have to be satisfied with the above "inverse" description.

Comment: Thank you.puting $a_{n}=1$ we simplify the question as follows: we identify all monic polynomial of degree n with $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. We search for covering space $M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$. It seems that I donot underestand something. Does your covering map cover wholle C^n? could you please more explain?

Comment: According to the original formulation of my question we search for  complex manifold M (Not orbifold)So do you think that the answer of my question is "No"? I mean that is it possible to prove that there is  no a complex manifold with those properies?

Comment: I think that the radical formula has  a  Riemann surface so this Riemann surface is the desired M

Comment: @AliTaghavi: See edited answer. I removed all my comments since they were incorporated in the edit.

Comment: There is  no  any obstruction for  compactification to obtain  a complex manifold again? There is  no any obstruction for holomorphic extension? I would appreciate if you explain more clear. Where you used the polynomial ness of $\sigma$. Could you please give me  a reference for some background?

Comment: I'm no specialist, but Riemann manifolds of algebraic functions are compact for the Zariski topology, and thus compact as projective manifolds by Chow's theorem. I hope I'm not too much mistaken saying things in that way (again, I'm no specialist of these questions). The reference I found is a paper by Zariski himself : *"The compactness of the Riemann manifold of an abstract field of algebraic functions."* (1944) with MR number MR0011573. I hope this covers your (essential) objection.